# PHP Sendmail Form Returns no Results

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I'm extremely new to php, roughly 2 days experience.
My conundrum is this:

My html is:

```
<div class="form">
  <form action="php/sendmail.php" method="post" id="contactwidget">
      <div class="inp_r"><input type="text" name="wname" id="wname" value="Name" size="22" tabindex="11" alt="Name" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inp_r"><input type="text" name="wemail" id="wemail" value="Email" size="22" tabindex="12" alt="Email" /></div>
   </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text_m"><textarea name="wmessage" id="wmessage" cols="28" rows="6" tabindex="13" title="Quick Message">Quick Message</textarea></td>
    <td class="text_r"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="loading"></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="wcontactemail" id="wcontactemail" value="info@joshuas.com" /></div>
                                    <div><input type="hidden" name="wcontacturl" id="wcontacturl" value="php/sendmail.php" /></div>
                                    <div><a href="#" id="wformsend" class="button" tabindex="14"><span>Send</span></a></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

My php is this:
<?php
  $email = $_POST['Email'] ;
  $name = $_POST['Name'] ;  
  $message = $_POST['wmessage'] ;

  $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";  

  mail( "info@gmail.com", "Message from Joshua",
    $message, "From: $email" );
?>
```

All that is returning is an email with  "Message from Joshua"

Any ideas??

Comment: So you ae not getting the message,right?

Comment: The input name of `name` and `email` is different in html

Answer (score 0):

you have to redirect the page in php script.

```
header( "location=wherever.php" );
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to test the output use this: http://papercut.codeplex.com/